# Does Dungeon Defenders support cross-platform multiplayer?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I would like to play with *Dungeon Defenders* in multiplayer mode with my PC copy (via Steam) and an Xbox copy. Is this possible?

Does Playstation 3 support cross-platform play?

Comment: PS3 and PC should support class-platform play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-platform multiplayer is supported, but as of April 2012, only between Mac and PC.

They appear to have removed the cross-platform support on Android, iOS, and the PS3 sometime in early 2012.

Comment: Note that this is not their fault - Microsoft doesn't allow cross-platform play for most (all?) XBox-360 games

Comment: Cross-platform between Windows and Linux isn't working either. So it's a least partly their fault :(

Answer (score 0):

All will be cross platform multilayer except for xbox. Currently cross platform multiplayer is going to be added with a.patch that should be out soon. Until then I cannot play buddy on pc.