# How can I play Dungeon Defenders cross-platform PC-PS3?

Tags: pc, ps3, dungeon-defenders

I found this: [Does Dungeon Defenders support cross-platform multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/does-dungeon-defenders-support-cross-platform-multiplayer)

So my question is not "if" but "how". How can I (on PC) play with PS3 players, or vice-versa?

Comment: as far as I can tell, you just join trendynet and its done automatically.

Comment: I don't follow. What are the steps? If I try the "Invite" button on PS3 I cannot select any Steam friends on PC.

Comment: I suspect you'll have to make a public game on trendy net, and then your friends will have to find it and join the game.

Comment: I believe you will find that the PS3 uses GameSpy and most people on the PC use Trendy. I am not saying if you both use GameSpy it will work (look at Borderlands afterall) but that is atleast one hurdle... Most of Sony's network is actually Gamespy underneath. The first Steam oriented PS3 game I am aware of was Portal 2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is actually currently supported.  It's listed as a feature, but it's also listed as "coming soon."

In a [reply to a forum thread](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?22873-XBOX-and-PS3-F.A.Q&p=203727#post203727), one of the developers of the game stated:

> We will post as we have more information. Cross-platform is a feature that we really want to implement. We also want to get fixes and improvements via patches to Console users. Unfortunately many things are simply out of our hands. We are working day and night on our product and hope you guys can bare with us.

This was the freshest data I could get, and it's dated November of 2011.

They've also mentioned that patching the console versions is a costly process ($10,000 according to other replies from the devs in that thread).

It's hard to say when the support will be there, as that's speculative and not really authoritatively answerable.

Comment: Thanks *sigh* I almost feel like a product was misrepresented now...

Comment: @zeno, many people in that forum thread feel/felt similarly to you...